# Changing Non Maximum Suppression to pick smallest box for OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv

Some quick googling will find you this sort of code for non maximum suppression.

```
import numpy as np

# Malisiewicz et al.
def non_max_suppression_fast(boxes, overlapThresh):
    if len(boxes) == 0:
        return []

    if boxes.dtype.kind == "i":
        boxes = boxes.astype("float")
    pick = []

    x1 = boxes[:,0]
    y1 = boxes[:,1]
    x2 = boxes[:,2]
    y2 = boxes[:,3]

    area = (x2 - x1 + 1) * (y2 - y1 + 1)
    idxs = np.argsort(y2)

    while len(idxs) > 0:
        last = len(idxs) - 1
        i = idxs[last]
        pick.append(i)

        xx1 = np.maximum(x1[i], x1[idxs[:last]])
        yy1 = np.maximum(y1[i], y1[idxs[:last]])
        xx2 = np.minimum(x2[i], x2[idxs[:last]])
        yy2 = np.minimum(y2[i], y2[idxs[:last]])

        w = np.maximum(0, xx2 - xx1 + 1)
        h = np.maximum(0, yy2 - yy1 + 1)

        overlap = (w * h) / area[idxs[:last]]

        idxs = np.delete(idxs, np.concatenate(([last],
            np.where(overlap > overlapThresh)[0])))

    return boxes[pick].astype("int")
```

This will return the largest box for a group of overlapping boxes whose area overlap by the percentage that can be indicated in the function.

How might you change this to return the smallest box in a group of overlapping boxes?

Answer (score 1):

I think the above code is wrong. May be you have made a small mistake while copying the code. But it can be make right by this small change.

`idxs = np.argsort(area)`

To get the minimum, you just have to make the following change in the above code:

```
# Malisiewicz et al.
def non_max_suppression_fast(boxes, overlapThresh):
  if len(boxes) == 0:
    return []

  if boxes.dtype.kind == "i":
    boxes = boxes.astype("float")
  pick = []

  x1 = boxes[:,0]
  y1 = boxes[:,1]
  x2 = boxes[:,2]
  y2 = boxes[:,3]

  area = (x2 - x1 + 1) * (y2 - y1 + 1)
  idxs = np.argsort(area)

  while len(idxs) > 0:
    last = len(idxs) - 1
    i = idxs[last]

    xx1 = np.maximum(x1[i], x1[idxs[:last]])
    yy1 = np.maximum(y1[i], y1[idxs[:last]])
    xx2 = np.minimum(x2[i], x2[idxs[:last]])
    yy2 = np.minimum(y2[i], y2[idxs[:last]])

    w = np.maximum(0, xx2 - xx1 + 1)
    h = np.maximum(0, yy2 - yy1 + 1)

    overlap = (w * h) / area[idxs[:last]]
    ### Modification
    selected_idx = np.where(overlap > overlapThresh)[0]
    selected_idx = np.concatenate(([last], selected_idx))
    min_area_idx = min(selected_idx, key=lambda i: area[i])
    pick.append(min_area_idx)
    ### Modification end
    idxs = np.delete(idxs, selected_idx)

 return boxes[pick].astype("int")
```

Comment: This does return the smallest box, but it won't give other non-overlapping boxes for me. I've been trying to modify it to get that to work but can't seem to figure anything out.

Comment: I didn't run the code on an example. Could you please give me an example. I will check it based on the example.

Comment: Yes, so I do my boxes as (x,y,w,h). `boxes = np.array([[1,1,50,50], [2,2,60,60], [70,70,50,50]])` and changing `x2` to `x2 = boxes[:,2] + boxes[:,0]` and `y2` to `y2 = boxes[:,3] + boxes[:,1]` should bring your code to what I'm using. The first and second box overlap but the third doesn't. It seems to get lost in the first iteration, but I can't find the right part of the loop to alter. Any `overlapThresh` < 1 should give the first box as your pick.

Comment: I made the appropriate changes and the code is running fine for the example you provided. Please feel free to let me know if you find any other bug in the code.

Comment: So now this is picking out the smaller boxes between non-overlapping boxes. When two boxes don't overlap it can re-introduce something that was selected out in a previous iteration. If there's a larger box that doesn't overlap with a smaller one, the smaller one gets picked here. Something for reference would be: `boxes = np.array([[130.,   6.,  20.,  31.],
       [ 83.,   5.,  19.,  32.],
       [ 84.,   6.,  17.,  30.]])`